# Is the sentence in passive or active voice?

Tags: verbs, tenses, present-perfect, passive-voice

We've been told not to run.
Which form of sentence is it? Active or Passive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is passive.  Active would be something like "Our parents have told us not to run."

Comment: Hello, mdoyle. Please read the reasons why this question has been put on hold. Answering an unsuitable question (ELU is aimed at linguists) encourages others.

Comment: I just have started learning English and got some questions which i didn't know where to ask. So i decided ask here. Why do you discourage people to help me.

Comment: Zaraza, questions for English Language Learners are bes suited to our sister site, **[English Language Learners Stack Exchange](https://ell.stackexchange.com)**.

Comment: Ooops,, seems like i made mistake. I thought this site is suited for English learners. My mistake.